# How to insert a LinkElement into a paragraph in Flex mobile project?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

Hi, everyone.
I'm working on a mobile project on Flex.
Once I get a paragraph from the internet, I need to recognize a specific string(may not appear just once)from that paragraph and make it clickable to trigger the other function in flex project.

I know the "LinkElement" helps, such as the content of this url:
http://bbs.9ria.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=42640
in which the code is like

```
var p:ParagraphElement=new ParagraphElement();
var tf:TextFlow=new TextFlow();
var nameLink:LinkElement=new LinkElement();
var nameSpan:SpanElement=new SpanElement();

nameSpan.text="LINK_TEXT";
nameLink.addChild(nameSpan);
p.addChild(nameLink);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
tf.addChild(p);
rt.textFlow=tf;
nameLink.addEventListener(FlowElementMouseEvent.CLICK, link_click_handler);
```

```
<s:RichEditableText editable="false" selectable="false" id="rt/>
```

However there's a simple linked text only, but I want other normal text(without link) in the same line.
The effect I want can be easily achieved by html like:

```
<p>
  unlinked_text1
  <a>linked_text</a>
  unlinked_text2
</p>
```

I've tried simply add another unlinked child at the place of "////////////////"
But it didn't work.
Is there any solution?
It's doesn't seem so hard, but I just can't make it.

Thanks for any sol in advance, please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ParagraphElement` object can have the following types of child objects: `SpanElement`, `LinkElement`, `InlineGraphicElement`, and `TCYElement`.

So why not just add additional `SpanElements` to your paragraph that contain the normal (non-linked) text:

```
var regularText:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
regularText.text = "this is some regular text";
paragraphElement.addChild(regularText);
```

If you already tried, this please show your code so we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for you answer =D
It turns out that I failed because that when I was trying to addChild(_SpanElement), I add the same child of the one I had added to the LinkElement.
Stupid me.
But, again, thanks a lot for you quick reply!!